# Substitution Method - How to find two tags with a newline inbetween using Perl?

Tags: perl

I have searched for a newline inbetween two lines in a html coding... I have tried out substitution method in perl...
Following is the coding i have tried...

File.txt

```
<body>
<p>God is great</p>
<p>He lives everywhere</p>
.......
</body>
```

Output:

```
file.html

<body>
<p>God is great He lives everywhere</p>
.......
</body>
```

Coding:
I have searched using substitution to merge the two lines...

```
print "Enter the filename: ";
chomp($file=<STDIN>);
open my $in,  '<', "$file.txt" or die "Can't read old file: $!";
open my $out, '>', "$file.html" or die "Can't write new file: $!";
while( <$in> )
{
s/(.+)<\/p>\n<p>/$1 /gs;
print $out $_;
}
close $in;
close $out;
```

But this not working
How can update this????

Answer (score 4):

You're reading the file one line at a time so there won't ever be a `\n` to match the substitution. Instead of using a `while` loop, you can read the file [in one go](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2009/08/a-one-line-slurp-in-perl-5.html):

```
my $html = do { local $/; <$in> };
```

Then do the substitution:

```
$html =~ s#</p>\n<p># #g;
print $out $html;
```

Notice I'm using an [alternative delimiter](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for the substitution to avoid having to escape the `/`.

Comment: I have got the output as i expected. It's very useful... i mentioned the next process to do with this loop that i have given above now.

Comment: You should ask a new question since this one has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `s` to your regex option and it should work:

```
s/(.+)</\p>\n<p>/$1 /gs;
                      ^^
```

Comment: @PLT You only read line by Line, so you can't match over more than one line. Store the lines in an string ant try to match it.

Answer (score 1):

The next script:

```
use 5.010;
use warnings;

my $html = do { local $/; <DATA> };
$html =~ s:</p>\n<p>: :igs;
say $html;

__DATA__
<body>

<p>par1</p><p>par2 </p>
<p> par3</p><p>par4</p>

<p> par5 </p>

<p>par6</p>

</body>
```

produces:

```
<body>

<p>par1</p><p>par2   par3</p><p>par4</p>

<p> par5 </p>

<p>par6</p>

</body>
```

if you change the regex to:

```
$html =~ s:</p>\s*<p>: :igs;
```

will get

```
<body>

<p>par1 par2   par3 par4  par5  par6</p>

</body>
```

and so on.

The main points:

- slurp the whole file into a variable
- substitute, with:

  - `i` - ignore case to match `<p>` and `<P>`
  - `g` - every occurence in the string, and
  - `s` - treat the string as an single line
- substitute into  one space, because if not, you will get concatenated stings, like from

```
$html =~ s:</p>\s*<p>::igs;
```

this

```
<body>

<p>par1par2  par3par4 par5 par6</p>

</body>
```

Note for example the `par1` and `par2`.

For slurping you should change the `<DATA>` to your `<$filehandle>`.

Comment: No need for `s` since you aren't using `.`

Comment: @RobEarl right, but isn't causes any problem and if the OP changes the something (e.g. will use `.` it will still works. ;)