# Acessing multiple files in a directory and write to another directory

Tags: perl

How to get the input files from one folder and perform the actions below for each file in the folder and store them in another output folder with the files as .xml

Input folder

```
main\123\1\file1.txt
main\456\2\file2.txt
main\789\3\file3.txt
```

Output folder

```
main\123\1\file1.html
main\456\2\file2.html
main\789\3\file3.html
```

Subroutine:

```
while( <$in> )
{
    s/(.+)<\/p>\n<p>/$1 /gs;
    print $out $_;
}
```

I want this subroutine to be run in all files...

Comment: It distracts from your current question when you don't even fix the bug that was addressed in [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25305395/1733163) from 3 hours before.  Take the time to edit this code with what people took the time to teach you or experts are likely to feel their efforts are wasted on you.

Answer (score 0):

```
chomp($sk = <>;) #Enter the direcory name for read the input files
opendir(mkh,$sk);
@az = readdir(mkh);
@match = grep{m/.*\.txt/} @az;
chomp($mkd  = <>;) #Enter the directory name for read the ouput files
mkdir "$mkd";
foreach (@match){
open(file,"$sk/$_");
open(new,">>$mkd/$_.html");
print new <file>;
}
```

In hope this bit of code helps you. But the output files name save with file extension.